# Getting CDF of variable-sized numpy arrays in Python using same bins?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas, statsmodels

I'd like to make a set of comparable empirical CDFs for a few numpy arrays (each of different length) and store these in a pandas dataframe:

```
a = scipy.randn(100)
b = scipy.randn(500)
# ECDF from statmodels
cdf_a = ECDF(a)
cdf_b = ECDF(b)
```

The problem is that `cdf_a.x, cdf_a.y` will be of different lengths of `cdf_b.x, cdf_b.y` and I would like these to be the same length, i.e. use same number of bins to compute the CDF so that these can be plotted on same scale from a pandas DataFrame. This is not possible:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"cdf_a": cdf_a.y, "cdf_b": cdf_b.y})
```

Since the cdfs are not of the same length. How can I bin `a` and `b` using similar bins when computing their CDFs, so that I get comparable same-length vectors back?

Is this the best solution?

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
v1 = cdf_a(bins)
v2 = cdf_b(bins)
```

Comment: It seems to me that your solution is the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a good solution:

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
v1 = cdf_a(bins)
v2 = cdf_b(bins)
```

Then `len(v1) == len(v2)` and these can be plotted as CDFs of `a, b` on the same scale.

Answer (score 1):

The way we use it in some goodness of fit tests is to stack the arrays, so they are defined on all points, points from both arrays.

Then use np.searchsorted to get the ranking, number of points in dataset 1 below x and number of points in dataset 2 below x.

If I remember correctly, look at scipy.stats.ks_2samp

```
data1 = np.sort(data1)
data2 = np.sort(data2)
data_all = np.concatenate([data1,data2])
cdf1 = np.searchsorted(data1,data_all,side='right')/(1.0*n1)
cdf2 = (np.searchsorted(data2,data_all,side='right'))/(1.0*n2)
```